# encajar imagen en contenedor para recortarla

Tags: html, css, div

Como puedo hacer que la imagen ocupe todo el contenedor? Mi idea es que quede como se muestra en la foto. Siendo elmarco rojo la imagen y el marco negro redondeado el contenedor de imagenes

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
#article{
    background-color: rgb(126,230,222, 0);
    padding: 0;
    height: 70%;
    width: 55%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0 0 10px;
}
```

```html
 <div id="article">
            <div id="slider">
                <figure>
                    <img id="imgSlider" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/207962/pexels-photo-207962.jpeg"/>
                </figure>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes poner un `width: 100%;` a la imagen Y quitar el margin del `figure`. El único problema es que la imagen así invade los bordes redondeados, puedes añadir un padding al `figure`:

```css
#article{
    background-color: rgb(126,230,222, 0);
    padding: 0;
    height: 70%;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0 0 10px;
}
figure{
    margin: 0px;
}
img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="article">
    <div id="slider">
        <figure>
            <img id="imgSlider" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/207962/pexels-photo-207962.jpeg"/>
        </figure>
    </div>
</div>
```

Segundo snippet: Aquí se ve recortada la imagen por el div.

```css
#article{
    background-color: rgb(126,230,222, 0);
    padding: 0;
    height: 70%;
    width: 55%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0 0 10px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;

}
figure{
    margin: 0px;
    height: auto;
}
img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="article">
    <div id="slider">
        <figure>
            <img id="imgSlider" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/207962/pexels-photo-207962.jpeg"/>
        </figure>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: estoy tratando de que la imagen al ocupar mas que el contenedor solo se vea aquello que este dentro del contenedor article. En la foto del esquema lo rojo seria la foto y lo nregro en div. Lo que quiero que se visualice es solo lo que este dentro del espacio del contenedor. Como si fuesa una capa encima de la otra. Vi que con z-index se podria hacer pero no lo logro realizar

Comment: Deja ver si entendí, ¿quieres que la imagen se vea afectada por el div como si estuviese recortada?

Comment: Eso es, la idea es que la imagen quede recortada por el tamaño del contenedor

Comment: He editado mi respuesta

Comment: gracias por la ayuda amigo ;D